# Same drive is mounted twice and one of them can't be unmounted?

Tags: mount

I have Raspian Jessie full installed with NOOBS.

I have formatted a drive using GParted to use for a Plex Server.

When I open up GParted I see that I have an entry

```
/dev/sda (with single partition)
partition: /dev/sda1 
name: plexstorage 
file system: ext4 
label: media
```

But in the File Manager (and terminal) I see what looks like two mounted drives

```
/media/pi/media
/media/pi/media1
```

Both contains part of data that I downloaded one day.

When I type umount /dev/sda1 `/media/pi/media1` disappears and only `/media/pi/media` remains.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see what looks like two mounted drives

Actually what you see are two directories -- that may be used as mount points, but then, pretty much *any* directory can be used as a mount point.  The ones in `/media` are conventionally used for fuse automounts (ie., those for non-privilleged users).

Try `mount | grep pi/media` and see how many lines of output there are.  If there are none, or only one, the data in the other (or both) directory/ies is just plain data that's in a directory; likely it ended up there by mistake when there was nothing mounted.

If this is a bit confusing:

- A mount point is a normal directory.
- That directory may contain data.
- If you or the system mounts a storage device on a directory that contains data, that data becomes inaccessible while the mount is there. Nothing bad will happen to it, however.

So, if one day I assume `/media/foo` has a USB stick mounted on it, and I copy `file.a`, `file.b`, `file.c` there but *there is no stick mounted there*, this is not a problem.  If later there is a stick mounted there with those files in it, these are separate copies from what was in the directory before anything was mounted on it. If later I look in that directory when I know the stick is not mounted, they will still be there, which is a clue that at some point (check the file modification time w/ `stat`) I copied files there by mistake.